# TROUBLE IN MULTIPLE SUBSELECT QUERY

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery, multiple-tables

I need to find the `name`, `function`, `officename` and the `salary` of all employee with the same function as `PETER` or a salary greater or equal than the salary of `SANDERS`. order by `function` and `salary`.

There are two tables: `office` and `employee`

table `office` contains:

```
officenumber

name

city
```

table `employee` contains:

```
employeenumber
name
function
manager
sal
officenumber
```

this is my current SQL query:

```
SELECT  NAME,
        FUNCTION,
        SAL
FROM    EMPLOYEE
WHERE   FUNCTIE   =   (SELECT     FUNCTION
                       FROM       EMPLOYEE
                       WHERE      NAME = 'PIETERS')
```

I'm stuck with the query.

Comment: hello PM77-1,  how does the next query look like? to create subselect for 'SANDERS' ?

Comment: @ Rega, make sure to check mark the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming this is SQL Server (you never specified), something like this should work.

```
SELECT
    e.name,
    e.function,
    e.sal,
    o.name AS officename
FROM employee e 
    JOIN office o ON e.officenumber = o.officenumber
WHERE
    e.function = (SELECT function FROM employee WHERE name = 'PIETERS') OR
    e.sal >= (SELECT sal FROM employee WHERE name = 'SANDERS')
ORDER BY e.function, e.salary
```

You'll have to tweak this a bit if you're working with MySQL or something else.

Answer (score 1):

Three things you need to do here:
1. join the two tables, since you need results from both tables
2. filter the results according to the two criterias
3. order the results:

The first part is easy, just need to join them according to the officenumber:

```
select e.name, e.function, o.name as officeName, e.salary from
  employee e inner join office o 
  on e.officenumber = o.officenumber
```

second part, simple where clause:

```
  where e.function = (select function from employee where name = 'PETER') 
  or e.salary >= (select salary from employee where name = 'SANDERS')
```

and the last, ordering:

```
  order by e.function, e.salary
```

Putting it all together:

```
select e.name, e.function, o.name as officeName, e.salary from
  employee e inner join office o 
  on e.officenumber = o.officenumber
  where e.function = (select function from employee where name = 'PETER') 
  or e.salary >= (select salary from employee where name = 'SANDERS')
  order by e.function, e.salary
```

Comment: Nir - I will edit your post to fix a typo (salery) and to remove "as" from table aliases. In Oracle you are not allowed to use "as" between a table name and its alias. You may use "as" between a column name (or an expression to be used as a column) and a column alias, and it's a good practice but it is never required; but for table aliases, it's simply not permitted. I see that the DB product wasn't known when you wrote this, but now it is, and it's Oracle - I am editing your post for future visitors to this thread.